# Where and how are callbacks in Mocha defined?

Tags: javascript, callback, mocha.js

In this code example for asynchronous code on the Mocha homepage:

```
describe('User', function(){
  describe('#save()', function(){
    it('should save without error', function(done){
      var user = new User('Luna');
      user.save(function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
        done();
      });
    })
  })
})
```

Where and how is the function `done` defined? It looks to me like either there should be a syntax error because it's just used without being defined, or there has to be some sort of "missing variable" handler, but I couldn't find anything like that in Javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
describe('User', function(){
  describe('#save()', function(){
    it('should save without error', function(done){
                                             ^^^^ look, there! ;-)
      var user = new User('Luna');
      user.save(function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
        done();
      });
    })
  })
})
```

It's a function passed by Mocha when it detects that the callback you pass to `it()` takes an argument.

**EDIT:** here is a very simple standalone demo implementation of how `it()` could be implemented:

```
var it = function(message, callback) { 
  console.log('it', message);
  var arity = callback.length; // returns the number of declared arguments
  if (arity === 1)
    callback(function() {      // pass a callback to the callback
      console.log('I am done!');
    });
  else
    callback();
};

it('will be passed a callback function', function(done) { 
  console.log('my test callback 1');
  done();
});

it('will not be passed a callback function', function() { 
  console.log('my test callback 2');
  // no 'done' here.
});

// the name 'done' is only convention
it('will be passed a differently named callback function', function(foo) {
  console.log('my test callback 3');
  foo();
});
```

Output:

```
it will be passed a callback function
my test callback 1
I am done!
it will not be passed a callback function
my test callback 2
it will be passed a differently named callback function
my test callback 3
I am done!
```

Comment: You're pointing out the place where I expect a "done is not defined" error. When it() is executed, it should be too late to do anything - and even then: how exactly does Mocha manage to define a function for this named but undefined parameter?

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt why do you expect it to be undefined? It's an argument declaration for a function (an anonymous function that is *passed* but not *called* at that moment). See my edit for how `it()` might be implemented (in simplified form).

Comment: Ah, thanks for the code. That finally forced me to realize I was an the entirely wrong track. I'm not used to mulltiply-nested function definitions...